# Angular6: How to link template variables to service's array with index being in paramMap

Tags: angular, service

*This question is more about design issues than solving a specific error.*

No matter how I try to do this I have this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: "_co.accountService.accounts[_co.accountIndex] is undefined"
```

OR (because I tried to use a `loading` variable which hides the template as long as the route `paramMap` has not emitted anything):

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'
```

I have an `Account.service` which is used by the `Account.component` to display a list of accounts, so upon initialization an `Account[]` is stored in the `Account.service`.

When I click on one of these accounts I'm changing the route to `account/1` for example which maps to the `AccountDetail.component`.
I already have the `Account[]` in `Account.service` fully populated and I don't want to initialize an `Account` variable in the `Account.service` (should I?).

I would like the `Account.component` **template** to directly refer to the index of the `Account[]` in `Account.service` by using a component variable `accountIndex` which is deduced from the `paramMap` observable.

First question: Does this make sense or should I treat this in a different way?

In the `Account.component` I don't need to store any informations, the whole template is directly bound to the `Account.service` (i.e `<li *ngFor="let account of accountService.accounts">{{ account.name }}</li>`) and it works fine.
I'm thinking about doing the same with `AccountDetail.component` like `{{ accountService.accounts[accountIndex].name }}`).

That way if any component alters an account all the others displaying them are automatically updated (is it a proper way to achieve this?).

**To sum up**: I want all my data to be stored in services (with only specific filtering parameters that are contextual to be stored in components) and I want most of it to be created during Account.component initialization for navigation to be as quick as possible.

How should I design this?

Thanks for reading and if anybody is willing to help me on this topic I can try to provide a plunker if needed (this question being about design I prefer design advice rather than code examples that I might not fully understand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Does this make sense or should I treat this in a different way?
1) Even if you do not need to use the information, it is a good practice to not to use service variable directly in the component's view.
2) Rather than sending the index in route parameter, i would recommend to achieve the goal with data sharing between parent-child components.

How should I design this? 
You should create a service and two components to do this.
Service will pass the data to parent component, which will show the list of all the accounts. Then, this list's items should bind the property to pass the account to child component. You can refer to some good blogs/angular guide on data sharing between parent and child component for more details on the topic. For example: 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction
https://ciphertrick.com/2017/07/24/parent-child-component-communication-angular/

Edited for sharing data with route params:
accounts init:

```
this.appService.accountsUpdated
.subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
  this.accounts = data;
});
```

accounts html:

```
   <a routerLink="/account/{{account.id}}">{{account.name}}</a>
```

Account-details:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((param:any) => {
      this.account = this.appService.getAccountWithID(param.id)[0];
    });
  }
```

Service:

```
  getAccountWithID(id: number) {
    return this.accounts.filter(acc => {
      return acc.id == id;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi Shahana, thank you for your answer.
I think I didn't express the context well enough or there's something I didn't understand about Angular.
The AccountDetail.component is not a child of Account.component, it is the only component called when going to 'account/:id' page. So I don't see how to take advantage of parent-child relation here.
Each account has its specific URL and when I go to one Account from the listing page, I'm going to a new page and Account.component is not there anymore. So I don't think I can use parent-child relation here.

Comment: Then about not using service variable directly, do you mean the services should not hold any data and just pass it along to the components which will then store it themselves? I have found references saying otherwise and that's actually my understanding of Services, they are not just interfaces because they hold data.
Or do you mean I should access the service's data in the template by calling a method inside the component? This way if data gets updated the others component won't know about it unless I call the method again.

Comment: Examples of services holding data: the MessageService in https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 which allows easy sharing of data between component or https://nodexperts.com/blog/angular-1-service-holding-data/ which says : "Data should also be stored in services" and "If data is stored in the controller then it will need to be fetched from somewhere when it is reinstantiated".
Can you elaborate on your design approach? Sorry for the numerous comments but there's a lot to talk about with these complex topics.

Comment: Hi, Regarding using service sharing the data: i agree that data should be shared via service but my reply might not be clear about it. I meant to not to use the service variable directly in the html view ('*ngFor="let account of accountService.accounts"'). Inject the service in the component and then write getter/setter methods in service to get/set the data to/from the components.

Comment: But if I create a method in the component then the template will not automatically get updated when the account array of Account.service is updated; unless the method returns accountService.accounts with accounts being an Observable and template using async pipe like `<li *ngFor="let account of (getAccounts() | async)"></li>`.
I'm not proficient with Observables yet and I don't think I can manage.

Comment: Regarding parent-child communication. If both the components are not related then you can send the id through routerlink from Account component and write another method into the service to filter the single object from accounts array. I will edit my answer to add some sample snippets.

Comment: I agree, seems what I was trying to achieve was overkill. I'll have to make sure any modification made to an account is replicated on the Account[] collection for when I go back to the account listing.
I'll try this way and get back to you.

Comment: Ok now in getAccount() I make sure that accounts is initialized first and then return the filtered version of accounts. It works fine and should be faster (though I'm querying indexedDB so it is fast either way). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're on the right track. As long as "Account" doesn't mean a private account that a user should log into.

If the user should be able to switch between accounts, and have access to all of them, then I would think that this could be very similar to the [heroes app](https://angular.io/tutorial). You can find a lot of ideas for implementation there.

As seen in the hero app, you can have two separate methods within the service. One, `getAccounts(){}`, for calling all accounts. And two, `getAccount(id)` for calling one specific account.

The variables to hold the selected account and/or the list of accounts could be stored within the service if you need to keep and pass them between components. There may be cases that you need to do this, but each page should also be able to retrieve what it needs without those variables too.

You might also look into component interaction. Storing the account in a parent component and passing it to child components as needed.

Parent/Child interaction information can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and it could look something like this:

**Account-Parent.component.html:**
`<account-child [selectedAccountChild]="selectedAccount"></account-child>`

**Account-Parent.component.ts:**
`selectedAccount: Account;
//connect to http-service to get the selected account`

**Account-child.component.ts:**
`@Input() selectedAccountChild: Account;`

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for those advice.
More info about my project: Accounts are private info specific to users but this is only aimed to be a demo project (want to find a job in Angular development but don't have professional experience with it). I'm actually storing everything on local indexedDB (not encrypted) because I want people to be able to try it online without exposing a server-side API which could have security flaws.
The next step would be to use ServiceWorkers to asynchronously sync local db with server db (useful for offline use which already work but tied to one device).

Comment: Concerning your recommandations about the service's methods that's actually what I'm doing now. I have getAccounts() to get all user's accounts and getAccount(id) to get a specific account. Both of these have a public property which is directly used by the components.

I just wanted to avoid making a call to indexedDB to get an Account when I already have all the accounts stored in the service, but I can use that array in getAccount method of account.service instead of trying something crazy directly in the component template.
Concerning parent-child, please check my answer to Shahana.